# fast-forward merge requests in gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I don't want to say that *all* our gitlab merge requests should be fast-forward-only, but for many simple ones the merge commits make commit history needlessly ugly. Is there any way to allow either style, and the maintainer can choose per MR? All I can find is a global per-project setting.

I can do it locally on the command line of course, and gitlab does seem to figure that out, but I feel like I must be missing a setting somewhere.

Comment: Did you test the [squash and merge](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/squash_and_merge.html) MR option ?

Comment: Yes, but squash-and-merge isn't the same thing at all. It, um, squashes all the commits into one, and then merges that (so a total of two commits). Fast-forward gives you a totally linear history with no merge commit at all. It's what you get on the command line with `git merge --ff-only`.